# Model Derivative API: What is the scope of a bucket?

Tags: autodesk, forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Can you please give a bit more information about the scope of a bucket? I experienced a situation that I started with searching for a bucket, and I did not find it into my actual list of bucket keys. 
Ok, but trying to create a new bucket with that key, I received the error that this was not possible because it was already a bucket with that key. {"reason":"Bucket already exists"}

Comment: Hi Willi! I recommend adding some more details to this question. For instance, I only see that you're working in Autodesk from the tags you've added. I recommend updating your question to include more detail about the steps you're taking. If you're coding against Autodesk's API, adding a code sample would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The bucket name is globally unique, so there is a chance that the bucket name you specified is actually used by some other app, so we usually would suggest you to make the bucket name something like "companyname-appname-bucketname" to avoid conflict, please check the following note in https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST/:

```
**bucketKey**: A unique name you assign to a bucket. It must be globally unique across all applications and
regions, otherwise the call will fail. Possible values: -_.a-z0-9 (between 3-128 characters in
length). Note that you cannot change a bucket key.
```

Comment: Thank you this explains the behavior! So it is a good idea to add a (UUID).ToLower() to the bucketkey?

Comment: Not necessary since it would be not easy to remember the bucket name with UUID.